expo-image-picker: check if device has no camera
The Problem
We also have to support zebra devices that have a laser scanner instead of a camera. We are trying to hide the camera icon(and other camera-related CTA's) if the device has no camera, but I couldn't find a way to do this with the expo-image-picker plugin.
I saw there was something here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#isavailableasync, but this is for @Web only.
The Question
What would be the best way to check in the code if the current device has a camera or not?

Does this answer your question? Check if device has a camera?

@user18309290 unfortunately that question/answers are for android/java. I need something for expo/react-native. Because expo pushes out prebuilds for both android and iOS and will overwrite any hacking done to those builds.

I suggest you use the Expo Device, it provides system information about the physical device, and maybe you get information to help hide the camera icon on the UI. Something like device type or the platform features can give the information, use according your scenario.

This is a great idea, I'll try it it when I have free time and if I can get it to work, I'll mark your answer. Thanks :)

Did you try it? Was it worked for you? If not, I can search for other solution

I can't remember why, but this didn't work for us. Instead we ended up going with import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info'; and then deviceHasCamera = await DeviceInfo.isCameraPresent();. Our issue was though it only works for android, but we couldn't think of any ios devices that wouldn't have a camera, other than apple watch(which we aren't supporting with this app)
